# How can upload and move maximum 15MB videos in PHP

Tags: php

```
$mimg=strtolower(substr($_FILES['video1']['name'], strrpos($_FILES['video1']['name'], '.') + 1));
$ext =  $lastid.".".$mimg;

$target_dir = "wp-content/plugins/videos/includes/uploads/".$ext;

$ss=move_uploaded_file($_FILES["video1"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir);

$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_dir,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
//$ex = $lastid.".".$imageFileType;

if($imageFileType != "mp4" && $imageFileType != "avi" && $imageFileType != "mov" && $imageFileType != "3gp" && $imageFileType != "mkv")
{
    echo "File Format Not Suppoted";
} 
else
{
    if($ss){
    $update2=$wpdb->query("update wp_videos set video1='".$ext."' where id='".$lastid."'");
        if($update2)
        echo "uploaded ";
    }
}
```

Comment: By increasing the upload size in server.  Search how to increase upload size in php.

Comment: It is unclear what you actually ask, sorry. Obviously the size of a possible file upload in your system is limited by php, but those settings are documented, you should have no issue learning how to change that. So what _is_ your question here?

Comment: What kind of problem are you facing? Is there any error message?

Comment: If you can't increase the upload size limit then you might have to look at chunking the data. createjs.com web site seems to have a pretty decent tutorial on this: http://creativejs.com/tutorials/advanced-uploading-techniques-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '15M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '15M');
```

Comment: Warning: POST Content-Length of 14655593 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0

Comment: I added the second line. Try with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value of `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in your `php.ini`

```
upload_max_filesize = 15M

post_max_size = 15M
```

you need to restart your server to use new configuration.

If you can't change your php.ini, you're out of luck. You cannot change these values at run-time; uploads of file larger than the value specified in php.ini will have failed by the time execution reaches your call to `ini_set()`

Comment: I have changed in the php.ini but it cannot update in the server

Comment: @Hak mat Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value of upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in your php.ini or .htaccess :

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Simply add this code in your theme’s functions.php file.
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '64M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '64M');
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
This code tries to increase upload maximum filesize, post maxiumum size, and maximum execution time limits for your WordPress site. However, this may not work for some WordPress websites.
In that case, you can try adding this code to your .htaccess file in your site’s root folder.
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300

If both of these methods fail, then you can try adjusting these values using php.ini file.

Ref: http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-upload-large-images-in-wordpress/
```